# 3d std::array in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, 3d, stdarray

I am early in c++. I want to define an 3d `std::array` in c++. when i define bellow array:

```
std::array<std::array<std::array<double,3>,4>, 4> DownSide = {
                         {{0,0.51,0.35},{0,0.51,0.35},{0,0.51,0.35},{0,0.51,0.35}},
                         {{0,0.51,0.35},{0,0.51,0.35},{0,0.51,0.35},{0,0.51,0.35}},
                         {{0,0.51,0.35},{0,0.51,0.35},{0,0.51,0.35},{0,0.51,0.35}},
                         {{0,0.51,0.35},{0,0.51,0.35},{0,0.51,0.35},{0,0.51,0.35}}
                        };
```

I see this error:

```
 error: too many initializers for ‘std::array<std::array<std::array<double, 3ul>, 4ul>, 4ul>’
       };
```

I googled this error find i mistak in numer brackets, but i dont know and find how must i write them.
How must i do?

Comment: TLDR; You have missing braces for aggragate initlaiztion, since the actual array is inside a structure. See here http://ideone.com/cTHReg

Comment: @StoryTeller, Thanks alot

Comment: The format doesn't work with the IDE. It scrambles the array formatting.